# Login with 2 different accounts simultaneously

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Enterprise powered computer with 2 user accounts - user1, user2. There is a monitor connected to it. I would like to allow user1 to login to this box via Remote Desktop Connection, while the physical terminal (monitor, keyboard, mouse) will be using user2 account. This should happen simultaneously, without interfering each other. Possible?

Comment: Not without hacks that I can not talk about here.  One user at a time with non-server Windows.

Comment: How about having full screen browser on the monitor and with Remote Desktop Connection another workspace, including the browser? That for me might also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using standard windows RDP.

Note that this is not a technical limitation, but one that microsoft implemented on purpose to ensure that people they think should pay for windows server are forced to do so, and to purchase Client Current Access Licenses for Terminal Services to support the number of users they wish to use. Windows server allows two concurrent connections by default without additional licensing.

In NT4 and Win2k this limitation was not present, but was introduced with Windows XP. Many people tried to bypass the limitation back in the early ot's, but I've never heard of a reliable way to make it work. From a quick google however it looks like people have made some progress on that front, so you may want to look it up, or look into another remote access product.

Comment: I will try to approach from different angle. On the monitor, I need only full screen browser. On RDC I need main workspace. Would it be possible to tweak Windows to thing it has 2 monitors attached (while only 1) and connect RDC to monitor1, while physical monitor to monitor2, where Chrome will be working.

Comment: do they need to run under two different users? if not, is the win10/11 Desktops feature sufficient to your need? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10 then you can switch between desktops so it sounds like what you might call a virtual monitor.

Comment: They don't need to run under two users. From the glance it looks like virtual desktops work only within physically connected monitors.

Comment: you only have one monitor right? I think you are going to need to better describe what you are looking for. I'm clearly having trouble parsing your request. Also your question, as asked, has been answered. it would be best to pursue your new question on a new thread, to reduce confusion, make your question and any answers discoverable to users who search for it later, allow you to better describe what you are looking for, and to reduce noise on the discussion.

Comment: I have only 1 physical monitor. It must show maximized browser. Then another operator may need any time to make Remote Desktop connection to the same box. The operator that was watching monitor should not be interrupted. Now if I login with RDC, monitor is locked. That should not happen.

Comment: OK, I'll compose another question. Thanks